# How to add only some columns from query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am trying to export data to CSV. I want only some fields to CSV in CodeIgniter but it's saying "You must submit a valid result object". Am I doing any wrong in my code?

Here's the code I tried:

```
    $projectdetails = $this->db->query('select hs_hr_employee.emp_number,hs_hr_employee.emp_firstname,hs_hr_employee.emp_middle_name,hs_hr_employee.emp_lastname,ohrm_customer.customer_id,ohrm_customer.name as customername,ohrm_project.project_id,ohrm_project.customer_id,ohrm_project.name as projectname,
                ohrm_project_admin.*, hs_hr_employee.*
                from hs_hr_employee,ohrm_customer,ohrm_project,
                ohrm_project_admin where 
                ohrm_project_admin.project_id=ohrm_project.project_id and 
                ohrm_project.customer_id=ohrm_customer.customer_id  and ohrm_project_admin.project_id=ohrm_project.project_id and ohrm_project_admin.emp_number=hs_hr_employee.emp_number
                ');


    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $delimiter = ",";
    $newline = "\r\n";
    foreach($projectdetails->result() as $projectdetails12)
    {
        $projectname=$projectdetails12->projectname;
        $customername=$projectdetails12->customername;
        $projectadmin=$projectdetails12->emp_firstname.$projectdetails12->emp_middle_name.$projectdetails12->emp_lastname;
        $downloadprojectdetails=array('projectname'=>$projectname,'customername'=>$customername,'projectadmin'=>$projectadmin);

        $filename = 'projectdetails.csv';
        $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($downloadprojectdetails, $delimiter, $newline);
        force_download($filename, $data);
    }

output using print_r
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [emp_number] => 3 [emp_firstname] => Suresh [emp_middle_name] => [emp_lastname] => Katiki [customer_id] => 1 [customername] => suresh [project_id] => 2 [projectname] => fff) [1] => stdClass Object ( [emp_number] => 2 [emp_firstname] => praveen [emp_middle_name] => [emp_lastname] => reddy [customer_id] => 2 [customername] => praveen [project_id] => 3 [projectname] => ota ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [emp_number] => 1 [emp_firstname] => chandra [emp_middle_name] => [emp_lastname] => kanth [customer_id] => 3 [customername] => chandra [project_id] => 1 [projectname] => orangehrm ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [emp_number] => 4 [emp_firstname] => aashish [emp_middle_name] => [emp_lastname] => madiri [customer_id] => 4 [customername] => aashish [project_id] => 4 [projectname] => test) )
```

Comment: show code of `$this->dbutil->csv_from_result()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->dbutil->csv_from_result` needs only query object not result object.
here you have to pass `$this->dbutil->csv_from_result($projectdetails,$delimiter, $newline);` not any array or result object

**Try below code**

```
$projectdetails = $this->db->query('select ohrm_project.name as projectname,
concat(hs_hr_employee.emp_firstname," ",hs_hr_employee.emp_middle_name," ", hs_hr_employee.emp_lastname) as projectadmin,
 ohrm_customer.name as customername
            from hs_hr_employee,ohrm_customer,ohrm_project,
            ohrm_project_admin where 
            ohrm_project_admin.project_id=ohrm_project.project_id and 
            ohrm_project.customer_id=ohrm_customer.customer_id  and ohrm_project_admin.project_id=ohrm_project.project_id and ohrm_project_admin.emp_number=hs_hr_employee.emp_number
            ');


$this->load->dbutil();
$this->load->helper('download');
$this->load->helper('file');
$delimiter = ",";
$newline = "\r\n";
$filename = 'projectdetails.csv';
if($projectdetails->num_rows() >0)
{
    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($projectdetails, $delimiter, $newline);
    force_download($filename, $data);
}
```

Comment: Not working its saying You must submit a valid result object

Comment: is your query returning any thing

Comment: its showing this error You must submit a valid result object

Comment: is there is another  way to download data in csv?

Comment: great! it worked what have you  done?can you please explain

Comment: `$this->dbutil->csv_from_result` needs only query object not result object. If it helped please mark as right